# Maximum and minimum value of arg

Tags: complex-numbers

Sketch on the argand diagram the locus :
$|z-2i+3|=\sqrt2$
I already sketched the diagram now I need to find the maximum and minimum value of $\arg(z+6)$

Comment: So far so good.  If you take your diagram and add $6$ to every $z$, what happens to the circle?

Answer (score 1):

hint...draw tangents to the circle from the point $z=-6$ and calculate the angles...